# curl query from external domain

Tags: php, mysql, curl

Hello dear stackoverflow's sons , I have a problem a very hard problem for me , ok my problem is like this I have a domain name example.com and that domain has a query string that query datas from database , and I have another domain name example2.com that will query and echo datas from domain name example.com but when I want to use mysql_connect('') on the domain example2.com using database mysql of domain example.com it gives me this error "access denied for user(db_user) ... (using password : yes) I tried with many things and I didn't fix it yet, and I was thinking if I can use curl to query datas from example.com/?dataid=1 in the domain example2.com and thanks in advance please I don't want some answers that says contact your hosting provider in order for them to enable remote mysql because they didn't want to :'( and thanks in advance for your help <3

Comment: What have you tried? Provide the problematic source code so people can analize it and help. Also, check if your username, password, hostname are correct

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a user on mysql in example.com like 'youruser@example2.com' with all privileges and look at your server if external connections is enabled.